# how to add the Android studio Navigation Drawer layout with a regular Activity class

Tags: android, android-activity, navigation-drawer, appcompatactivity

I have been working an an complex app that the *Main Activity* extends the **Activity class**. But now I want to add a *Navigation Drawer*, but the Android studio built in **Navigation Drawer layout** extends the **AppcompatActivity**. I don't know how to bridge between them. I have invested to much time in my app code to change it now. I need an idea how to solve this problem.

Comment: You just need to add DrawerLayout to your activity.

Comment: Try googling how to add DrawerLayout to activity if you won't find anything I'll be happy to post answer :)

Comment: I googled it and found an answer, now I will try implementing it an see if it works. I wanted to use the built in template in android studio because it is the most updated, but I see I will have to try an older code.

Comment: It didn't work because all the examples I find using the XML files are all extending AppCompatActivity witch was my problem form the beginning. My app extends the Activity class and I need a way to implement a Navigation drawer with out using AppCompatActivity.

Answer (score 0):

Try this implementation of a MaterialDrawer library navigation drawer for your application. It follows the Android Design Guidelines. There is a Header with profiles (AccountHeader), a MiniDrawer for Tablets (like Gmail), provide custom DrawerItems, custom colors, custom themes etc.

It works beautifully. [GitHub code and full credits here.](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer)

Comment: What you sagest is coding everything only in Java with out XML. But the problem is that Google is changing the code all the time and with out an XML file I am working blind, witch mean that maybe the code will work now but down the line one deprecated command I wont know how to fix it.

Comment: Check out this link for creating a navigation drawer from Google https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer#java